# Calculate the binomial probability for $N$ events

Tags: probability, statistics

### Background

I have a question that I've been thinking about a lots and haven't been sure about the answer. Here is the question.

Bob and Alice play a game called "Change and Guess".

> Basically, Alice has an array including $800000$ numbers that Bob has to guess. Since there are a lot of numbers to guess so Alice decides to give Bob all the numbers ( $800000$) in the array. However, Alice will first change $512$ numbers at random in the array then give the array to Bob. Bob's also aware of that every time he asks there will be $512$ numbers that are changed in the array. Bob can ask as many times as he wants and will have to guess the numbers after that. Bob takes the strategy that counting the appearances for each number in the array and take the majority one to find out the original value for each number. He'll do that process for $800000$ numbers and bring them back to Alice.
> How many times that Bob as least has to ask in order to have $99.9999999\%$ chance of guessing all the numbers right using the mentioned strategy above**

Here is an example:

**Since the length of the array is big and to keep everything simple, the example below is just a simplified version of the question demonstrates how the Bob/Alice game works. The length of the array is just 5 numbers and Alice changes only 1 number each time in the example but It will be 800000 numbers and Alice can change 512 numbers in the array for real question.**

Alice has an array $X = [1,2,3,4,5]$
Bob asks Alice for $3$ times. Alice then will change some numbers in the array and then give them to Bob each time. The $3$ arrays can look like:

$$X_1 = [1,2,3,4,6]$$

$$X_2 = [1,2,3,10,5]$$

$$X_3 = [100,2,3,4,5]$$

Now Bob can look at those arrays and start guessing the values.

So for each position for $3$ arrays, Bob counts the appearance and picks the highest one with the hope that the majority one will be the original one.

First position : $1$ appears $2$ times, $100$ appears $1$ times. Bob picks $1$.

Second position : $2$ appears $3$ times. Bob picks $2$.

Third position:  $3$ appears $2$ times, $2$ appears $1$ times. Bob picks $3$.

..
..

Then at the end, Bob's guessing array will be $X = [1,2,3,4,5]$

### My Attempt

So this is what I thought so far:

The probability of picking one number from an array is $512/800000 = 0.00064$.
So for $N$ times, in order for this strategy to be failed, there must be at least one number that is picked at least $(N/2) + 1   times (\gt50\%)$ so the changed valued will get picked based on majority vote.

Based on the binomial probability formula. The probability of an event happens exactly $K$ times out of $N$ times is:
[Binomial probability formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLuj8.png)

In this case, we need to calculate the probability for $K$ from $(N/2) +1$ to $N$ . This will be calculated by the sum of applying the formula for $K$ from $(N/2) + 1$ to $N$. I'll call that

$$P(k\ge (N/2) +1 )$$

I ran $N$ from $2$ to $100$:

$$N=2, P(k\ge (N/2) +1 ) = 4.0960000000000007e^{-7}$$

$$N=3, P(k\ge (N/2) +1 ) = 1.2282757120000002e^{-6}$$

$$N =4, P(k\ge (N/2) +1 ) =  1.0480726835200003e^{-9}$$

$$N =5, P(k\ge (N/2) +1 ) = 2.6189240618450956e^{-9}$$

$$N=6, P(k\ge (N/2) +1 ) = 2.5140061068171685e^{-12}$$

$$\vdots$$

So on it keeps getting closer to $0$.

So in order to have $99.9999999\%$ success, Bob probably need $4$ iterations at least.

I'm wondering that whether there was any approach other than mine for this question or not. Is there anything else I haven't considered yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: This is not clear at all.  What does "So he comes up with a strategy that he prepares N same arrays and lets Alice do the "change" part for N times." mean, for instance?  More broadly, what difference does it make if Alice changes her numbers or not?  In the end, it's still just a list of numbers for Bob to guess, yes?  I suggest rewriting for clarity.  State the rules clearly and simply.  Perhaps work out an explicit example with small numbers.

Comment: At what point does Bob ever see any given array's values?  The X=80000 array gets x=512 changes made by Alice, but then what? Does Bob see all X, or does he only get to view a smaller subset of that?

Comment: Please edit your post to state the rules clearly and simply.  Do not leave critical information for the comments.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @AmateurDotCounter I revised the problem  and hope it's clear to everyone now!Thanks all!

Comment: @lulu  I revised the problem and hope it's clear to everyone now!Thanks all!